# How to get value [underline:PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font:private] form output PHP_WORD?

Tags: php, docx, doc, phpword

I want to get value of [underline:PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font:private] from output PHP_WORD, I do not know how, please show me how. Thank.
(sorry about my english)

```
[0] => PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Text Object
(
    [text:protected] => C
    [fontStyle:protected] => PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font Object
        (
            [aliases:protected] => Array
                (
                    [line-height] => lineHeight
                    [letter-spacing] => spacing
                )

            [type:PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font:private] => text
            [name:PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font:private] => Tahoma
            [hint:PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font:private] => 
            [size:PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font:private] => 12
            [color:PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font:private] => 
            [bold:PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font:private] => 
            [italic:PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font:private] => 
            [underline:PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font:private] => single
            [superScript:PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font:private] => 
            [subScript:PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font:private] => 
            [strikethrough:PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font:private] => 
            [doubleStrikethrough:PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font:private] => 
            [smallCaps:PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font:private] => 
            [allCaps:PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font:private] => 
            [fgColor:PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font:private] => 
            [scale:PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font:private] => 
            [spacing:PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font:private] => 
            [kerning:PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font:private] => 
            [paragraph:PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font:private] => PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Paragraph Object
```

Full Data Here : https://pastebin.com/raw/prfejCAup

Answer (score 0):

[`\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Text`](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/src/PhpWord/Element/Text.php) has a method `getFontStyle()` to access the underlying font style.

Referring to [`\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font`](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/src/PhpWord/Style/Font.php), the method `getUnderline()` will return the value for the underline style you are trying to get.

Therefore, to get what you are after, try:

```
$underline = $elements[0]->getFontStyle()->getUnderline(); // 'single'
```